# Расстояния между flex элементами при justify-content: center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нашел статьи про flex - https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/ и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content. В них сказано, что при атрибуте justify-content: center

> center

> Элементы располагаются друг за другом в центре контейнера по главной оси.

Но каково расстояние между flex элементами (и до начала и после блока с flex элементами) при таком значении атрибута justify-content?

Comment: никакое \\\\\\\

Comment: То, которое вы сами зададите марджином или паддингом

Comment: @Arcadiy приведите пример пожалуйста. Как можно обратиться к flex элементу, для того чтобы задать марджин или паддинг для элемента?

Comment: @wfamilyweb https://codepen.io/sochi-russia/pen/XWeOazP

Comment: @Arcadiy а почему несмотря на то, что везде установлен flex-direction: row, элементы .blockone, ..., .blockfive выводятся не в строчку, а в столбик?

Comment: @wfamilyweb блокам нужно прописать ширину. Исправил код, посмотрите